# How to use Warshall's Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, discrete-mathematics

This question appeared on my homework and I don't have the slightest idea how to solve it!

```
Let A = (1, 2, 3, 4) and let R be the relation on A whose matrix is given by:

1  1  0  1
1  0  1  0
1  1  0  0
0  1  0  1

Compute MR∞ (M infinity R?) using Warshall's Algorithm.
```

Can anybody help me with this question? And if you can show it to me in steps, that would be great!

Answer (score 6):

The starting point is the matrix

$$M_R=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&1\\
1&0&1&0\\
1&1&0&0\\
0&1&0&1\end{bmatrix}\;.$$

Let $W_0=M_R$, and successively compute $W_1,W_2,W_3$, and $W_4$. (More generally, if $M_R$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, we let $W_0=M_R$ and compute $W_1,W_2,\dots,W_n$.) For each $k>0$, $W_k$ is calculated using column $k$ and row $k$ of $W_{k-1}$. Thus, $W_1$ is computed using column $1$ and row $1$ of $W_0=M_R$, $W_2$ is computed using column $2$ and row $2$ of $W_1$, and so on. The procedure for getting $W_k$ from $W_{k-1}$ is as follows:

- **Step 1:** Transfer all of the $1$’s in $W_{k-1}$ to the corresponding positions of $W_k$.

Doing that for $k=1$ in this specific problem, we get

$$W_1=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&&1\\
1&&1&\\
1&1&&\\
&1&&1\end{bmatrix}\;.$$

- **Step 2.** List separately the rows that have $1$’s in column $k$ and the columns that have $1$’s in row $k$.

Here those are rows $1,2$, and $3$ and columns $1,2$, and $4$.

- **Step 3.** Pair each of the row numbers with each of the column numbers, and put a $1$ in the corresponding position of $W_1$ if there isn’t one there already. Put $0$’s in any remaining empty positions.

We get the pairs $(1,1),(1,2),(1,4),(2,1),(2,2),(2,4),(3,1),(3,2)$, and $(3,4)$ and therefore the matrix

$$W_1=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&1\\
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&0&1\\
0&1&0&1\end{bmatrix}\;.$$

Now repeat with $k=2$. The first step gives us

$$W_2=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&&1\\
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&&1\\
&1&&1\end{bmatrix}\;.$$

The second step gives us row numbers $1,2,3,4$ and column numbers $1,2,3,4$, so the third step gives us every possible pair, and

$$W_2=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1\end{bmatrix}\;.$$

In principle we still have to calculate $W_3$ and $W_4$, but it should be clear that they will be the same as $W_2$: the algorithm ensures that if an entry in some $W_{k-1}$ is $1$, that entry remains a $1$ in $W_k$ and hence in $W_{k+1},\dots,W_n$.

Thus,

$$M_{R^\infty}=W_4=W_2=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1\end{bmatrix}\;,$$

and the transitive closure of $R$ is the total relation $A\times A$ containing every possible ordered pair of elements of $A$: everything in $A$ is related by $R^\infty$ to everything in $A$.

I could express the algorithm more formally in terms of the Boolean operations $\land$ and $\lor$ on $\{0,1\}$: if $w_{ij}^{(k)}$ is the $(i,j)$ entry of $W_k$, the steps that I described verbally above amount to saying that

$$w_{ij}^{(k)}=w_{ij}^{(k-1)}\lor\left(w_{ik}^{(k-1)}\land w_{kj}^{(k-1)}\right)\;.\tag{1}$$

This is because $w_{ik}^{(k-1)}\land w_{kj}^{(k-1)}=1$ if and only if $i$ is in the row list and $j$ is in the column list formed at the second step of the algorithm. Thus, $(1)$ sets $w_{ij}^{(k)}$ to $1$ if and only if either $w_{ij}^{(k-1)}$ was already $1$ (corresponding to the first step of the algorithm), or $(i,j)$ is one of the pairs formed in the third step of the algorithm.

Comment: Turns out if you try to use this algorithm to get a randomly generated preorder (reflexive transitive relation) by first setting the diagonal to 1 (to ensure reflexivity) and off-diagonal to a coin flip (rand() % 2, in C), curiously enough you "always" (10 for 10 in my experiment) get nothing but 1's in your preorder matrix.  Setting the off-diagonal to !(rand() % 5) works a lot better.