# Warshall's algorithm in transitive closure

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, relations

Let $A=\{0,1,2,3\}$ and let $R$ and $S$ be the relations on $A$ described by the matrices

$M_R=
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$

$M_S= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

> **Question 1**
>
> Compare $M_{R^{-1}}$, $M_{R \cap S}$, $M_{R \circ S}$.
>
> **Question 2**
>
> Use Warshall's algorithm to compute the transitive closure of $R \cup S$.

Can anyone help me step by step how to deal with these matrices?
Especially Warshall's algorithm, I really don't understand even though studying my lecture notes.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: For starters you might look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369134/how-to-use-warshalls-algorithm) and my answer to it: it contains a worked example of Warshall’s algorithm.